# Change value in one numberfield based on two other fields

Tags: forms, extjs

I create 3 numberfields in a form:

```
{
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Inhuur',
            name: 'inhuurPrijs',
            inputId: 'inhuurPrijs',
            emptyText: '0'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Marge %',
            inputId: 'inhuurMarge',
            emptyText: '0',
            maxValue: 100,
            minValue: -100
        },
        {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Verhuur',
            inputId: 'verhuurPrijs',
            emptyText: '0'
        },
```

In field 'inhuurPrijs' i fill in a number. For example 100. Based on the field 'inhuurMarge' i want to make the price in 'verhuurPrijs'. inhuurMarge is a percentage field. So when the user choose the value '10' the 'verhuurPrijs' should be 110.

I tried listeners but those aren't working. And to make it even more complicated.....if i fill in 'inhuurPrijs' & 'verhuurPrijs' i want to calculate the percentage between them and place that in 'inhuurMarge'

Is this possible in a form?

Comment: Listeners should work fine, show what code you tried for the listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use listeners, attach them to the fields to detect when changes are made and run your calculation and update the total.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/i9n)

Here is the code in case the above link breaks:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Basic Form',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            bodyPadding: 5,
            width: 350,

            defaults: {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                listeners: {
                    change: function(field, newVal, oldVal) {
                        console.log("Calculating");
                        var amount = Ext.getCmp('fieldAmount').getValue();
                        var markup = Ext.getCmp('feildMarkup').getValue();
                        var total = Ext.getCmp('fieldTotal');
                        if (amount > 0 && markup > 0) {
                            total.setValue( 
                                amount + ((markup/amount) * 100)
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'amount',
                name: 'amount',
                id: 'fieldAmount'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'markup',
                name: 'markup',
                id: 'feildMarkup'
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'total',
                name: 'total',
                id: 'fieldTotal'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Note: You should probably disable the total / calculated field so that it cannot be manually edited.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I've implemented, is to add listeners on update/datachanged event of the store and not on the form fields, in this way all the magic happens even if you change data somewhere else, even from console, not only that particular form.

```js
myStore.on('update', function(store, rec, op, fields, details, eOpts){
    // run this only if desired fields have changed
    if (fields && fields.some(function(item){
            return /^amount/.test(item); // if field name starts with 'amount'
            //return ['field_1', 'or_field_2', 'percentage_3'].indexOf(item) >= 0; // validation based on custom names, of course that still can be done using RegEx
      })
    ) {
        // custom number round function, see bellow why
        var total = Ext.Number.round(rec.get('amount_one') * rec.get('amount_two') / 100);

        rec.set('total', total);
    }
 });
```

I have the total field in my Model, and retrieve it's default value from the server (if you want), but I'm setting `persist: false` on it, in order not to send it back to the server.

Regarding custom number round method, I've discovered hard way that JavaScript rounding methods are not quite precise, meaning:

```js
Number((1.005).toFixed(2)); // 1 instead of 1.01
Math.round(1.005*100)/100; // 1 instead of 1.01
```

Jack Moore built a custom function which seems to correct this which I've implemented in `Ext.Number` class, so all the credits for this goes to him: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/rounding-in-javascript/

```js
function round(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value+'e'+decimals)+'e-'+decimals);
}
```

Another improvement is that it's using direct record access (or even associated data if needed), and not ComponentQuery which isn't so performant.

Lately I'm avoiding `Ext.getCmp()` as much as possible, but if I need to address components in the view (or event parent views) I'm using `this.getView().lookupReference()` or selectors like `.up()` or `.down()` instead.